# What is the better way than joining 3 tables?

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I have to join 3 tables somewhere on my project.
Here is example tables and columns:

```
Table-1 : posts 
Columns1: id,owner,title,post,keywords

Table-2 : sites
Columns2: id,name,url

Table-3 : views
Columns3: id,post,view
```

When I join all these tables it happens such a little huge query:

```
SELECT title,post,keywords,name,url,view
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN sites ON sites.id=posts.owner 
LEFT JOIN views ON views.post = post.id 
WHERE posts.date BETWEEN '2010-10-10 00:00:00' AND '2010-11-11 00:00:00' 
ORDER BY views.view DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Is it the only way or could I do something else to get better performance?

This is my current query's EXPLAIN. Above one is just an example.
[image: MysqlFront EXPLAIN Result]

Comment: please post output of `explain` to check your indexes are being used correctly

Comment: Does 'views' maintain a simple count? Or a separate entry for each view of each post?

Comment: I'm not sure what "it happens such a little huge query" is supposed to mean.  Lots of results?  Slow query?  The SQL itself is bigger than you've expected?  And "a little huge query"?  Which is it?  Little or huge? ;)

Comment: @tobyodavies I am not that senior to understand your sentence, sorry. I tried to put `explain` start of my query but I didn't understand the result.
@Babak Naffas it is simple for now but I will add some other columns later.

Comment: @Ahmen, thats why i said to post it, we can help you with what it means

Comment: @tobyodavies I edited post with EXPLAIN result of my query. Thanks for interest.

Comment: @Ahmen, see that phrase "using file sort" and the `Null` possible indexes... thats a bad thing. you need an index on `views.view` since that is what you want your output sorted by

Comment: @tobyodavies wow thanks. I added an index and 4822 dicreased to 8. It was magical, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your relations are guaranteed, in other words non-nullable foreign keys, then the query will perform better if it uses inner joins instead of left joins.  Although this query does not appear to be large or complex enough to seriously be suffering from performance issues.

Comment: yes, my relations are guaranteed to be non-nullable. Than I will change LEFT JOINs into INNER JOINs . Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for all answers. All answers worth to learn about. In my position using INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN is seems better usage.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a particularly "Huge" query.  Have you ran query analyzer and checked for where the slow point is and then checked your indexes?

Re: Analyzer - Microsoft keeps moving it, but in 2008 Management Studio there are several options for showing the execution plan.  Once you see the execution plan you can see where the problems are.  Look for a single action taking 80+% of your time and focus on that.  Things like Table Scans are an indication that you could speed it up by tweaking indexes.  (There are downsides to indexes as well, but worry about that later).

Comment: Yeah this is not huge query but I am not a senior developer and I have doubts about project's future. If I would have -probably I will have- thousands of posts will it be still not problem? I didn't run query analyzer and never used it. Is it not necesarry to think about this kind of queries?

Comment: @Ahmet - I'm not entirely sure of what you are asking.  Are you asking if it may be a problem after an arbitrary increase in database size?  As far as query analyzer goes, it's a great tool you should learn, even as a junior developer.  I'll add a link for you.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I am afraid of future. Now there are just 5k posts and views. But this is not the only query and I don't know if there is a better way of this. I will also look for query analyzer.

Comment: @Ahmet - Regarding the future, it helps to know a little bit about your usage scenarios and expect growth rates.  If you're not very experienced I wouldn't try to build for an unknown user base too far in advance.  Use this time to learn more so that when the future happens you can deal with whatever it may be.

Comment: thank you very much for suggestions. I have a long way to walk to be a senior developer. Wish it takes little time. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

That's not a huge query by any stretch of the imagination.

How slow is it really?

Maybe if views doesn't contain any more information than what you've shown, you should just have a view count be a field of posts. No need for it to be its own separate table unless you're actually storing some information about the views themselves, like user-agent strings or time.

Comment: I didn't analyzed query cause I am not sure about how do I. I seperated views table because I will add some other columns later. Do you think will this query still useful after 10k posts and views?

Comment: +1 Good point. If the relation between views and posts will always be a 1:1 it will likely be better off all stored in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

If your POSTS table is particularly large (>100K rows?) then one thing you could do is to load the time-filtered posts into a temporary table and join on that temp table.

Comment: thanks for answering. It is a baby project now but I think it will have 10k posts in a year. I will also look for your suggestions. Thank  you.